# Prebuilt GVim 7.3. binaries with +python support

Tags: python, vim, windows-xp

Apart from compiling GVim, is there anywhere where one can downlod the binaries with +python support already included?

***Edit :: Apologies for forgotting again. I'm looking for Windows binaries.***

Comment: That's actually a little hard since there are different versions of Python it would have to be linked against. I use Gentoo Linux so I don't have that problem. Just set the "python" USE flag and it's done. ;-)

Comment: Depending the distribution you are using you can find binaries of gvim already compiled. That's for instance the case with arch linux: http://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gvim/

Comment: @Keith - From what I understood (while googling this matter), it is only a matter of choosing between Python 2.x and 3.x. And 3.x. support is still not stable (there are patches, but ...), nor common. Most py/vim scripting is done in 2.x.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okey, problem solved.

On *[www.vim.org](http://www.vim.org)* when downloading Vim one must take the *OLE* version, along with the runtimefiles archive. Upon unzipping try for example

***:python print('Whatcha doing Doc?')***

and see what error it will give. You should see something along the lines of ... yadda yadda **python27.dll.** There's your clue. That version was compiled with Python 2.7. in mind, so go to *[www.python.org](http://www.python.org)* and download it. Upon installing repeat the test print in Vim - it should work now. I tried it with Vim 7.3 (current) and Python 2.7.2. (current) but expect it should similarly for older versions as well. Just be sure to *pair them up*.

Comment: If I could up vote this a thousand times I would. This is simple yet overlooked. Thank you!!!

Comment: I've installed python 2.7.3 and vim on windows 8 - all the correct 32 bit versions. When I type this however I get the "sorry the command is not available in this version"

Comment: @Diego, you must have vim compiled with +python option. Execute this: `redir => ver | execute "normal :silent version\<CR>" | redir END | echo matchstr(ver, '[+-]python')` and see if you get `+python` or `-python`

Answer (score 2):

You can download the [vim without cream](http://cream.sf.net/download.html). They usually compile 
frequently with the latest patches.
The problem for me is that they compile
against python2.6 and I am more interested in using python2.7.
Note that the installer does not actually ship with python, you have to install python separetely.

Comment: Same here (regarding py2.7). I'll check out the link.